# Sitecore 8.2 Update 1, Using SOLR for both CMS search and Web search

Tags: solr, content-search, cloud

- Can SOLR be used for Sitecore search and website search with latest
  release 8.2.1. the solution needs to be deployed on Cloud
- Is it required to have Coveo and SOLR both in order to implement search for
  Sitecore 8.2.1?
- What is the recommended best practice to use for SOLR search implementation for both CMS and Web search
- Are there any code samples available?

I have already gone though the following links: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/configure_a_search_and_indexing_provider

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/setting%20up%20%20maintaining/search%20and%20indexing/walkthrough%20setting%20up%20solr

Comment: can you clarify what kind of code samples do you need?

Comment: Any implementations done using Azure search or SOLR for querying. I know indexing is straight forward for CMS only index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLR can be used with 8.2 update 1 (and 2). However, you need to install SOLR yourself, or choose for the azure search provider, which can be provisioned while provisioning your Sitecore PaaS Services to Azure.

It's not required to have Coveo AND SOLR in 8.2.1. SOLR on itself is possible, Azure search can be used, lucene may be used (but not in the cloud). Coveo is an addition to the existing search providers. When using Coveo, you HAVE to have search providers like SOLR or Azure Search configured, as Coveo is only used for the websites, not for the CMS search.

Comment: Thanks Bas, I have heard that there are challenges with SOLR on cloud environments where you have auto-scaling enabled. The indexes get corrupt if the new server is spun up or SOLR server is restarted, and indexes need to be re-built. Can one use Azure search for both CMS search and website search both? or is it like Coveo where one need to have SOLR/Lucene for the cms?

Comment: Are there any limitations of Azure search with Sitecore as well? Azure search for sitecore is pretty new, hence we want to make an informed decision.

Comment: I can't consult you on the use of Azure Search, as I don't have enough experience with it yet

Comment: No issues @Bas. I got an answer for Azure that it is used on both CM and Web searches.

Answer (score -2):

CMS & Web search are part of your index configuration & I don't think its possible to have two different search provider in your Sitecore instance.  Obviously two providers can support Cloud feature if they are not breaking the above-mentioned rule. Also if your instance in cloud & SOLR are interactive (able to perform rebuild indexing)without any permission issue then you should follow normal solr search provider as mentioned. If you are looking for some other cloud(AZURE) based search provider then you can see AZURE Search https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sitecore-81-azure-search-provider-part-1-indexing-jamie-scott

Comment: It's possible to have [multiple search providers in Sitecore 7.5+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29078699/can-we-use-solr-and-lucene-both-together-in-sitecore/29080994#29080994). Sitecore 8.2 Update-1 also now support Azure search OOTB (which is what the OP is referring to)

Comment: @jammykam, thanks for the info but wondering how would we manage rebuild indexing when we have different providers through Sitecore interface. Especially Coveo comes with additional Sitecore interface changes for Rebuild index AFAIK.

Comment: It still uses the standard Sitecore interface(s) for rebuilding indexes - from the ribbon or the Control Panel. You can also set different indexing strategy in config for each index.#